# ¿Cómo incluyo una función void dentro de una función bool?

Tags: c++, funciones

¿Cómo puedo incluir el resultado de la función de `void` en la `bool`?

Necesito compararla, el error me recae en la función `bool`. Dice:

> No matching function for call to Fracción::elevarFraccionAlaN()

```
void elevarFraccionAlaN(int N){
    float obtenerDivisionDecimal, Potencia, i;

    i=1;
    Potencia=1;

    while(i<=N){
        Potencia=Potencia*obtenerDivisionDecimal;
        i++;
    }   
}


bool esMenorQue(){

    if (elevarFraccionAlaN()<obtenerDivisionDecimal())
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si es una función-miembro de clase, siempre puedes usar una variable-miembro para almacenar el resultado:

```
class Algo {
  float m_estado;

public:
  void elevarFraccionAlaN( int N ) {
    float obtenerDivisionDecimal, Potencia, i;

    i = 1;
    Potencia = 1;

    while( i <= N ) {
      Potencia=Potencia*obtenerDivisionDecimal;
      i++;
    }

    m_estado = Potencia;
  }

  bool esMenorQue(){
    elevarFraccionAlaN( );

    if( m_estado < obtenerDivisionDecimal( ) )
      return true;

    return false;
  }
};
```

<sub>Desde luego, no entiendo esos requisitos tan raros ...</sub>

Por cierto, la función `elevarFraccionAlaN( )` ha de llamarse con un argumento ...

Answer (score 3):

No es posible hacer lo que pretendes mientras la función devuelva `void`. Por definición, una función `void` **no devuelve nada**, y no puedes usar la *nada* para obtener *algo*.

Lo lógico, viendo tu código, es que la función devolviese un `float`:

```
float elevarFraccionAlaN(int N){
    float obtenerDivisionDecimal, Potencia, i;

    i=1;
    Potencia=1;

    while(i<=N){
        Potencia=Potencia*obtenerDivisionDecimal;
        i++;
    }

    return Potencia;  
}
```

Esto ya serviría para tus propósitos

> Es un trabajo de la U e indica que debe usarse void

En ese caso y muy a mi pesar, tendrás que devolver el resultado como referencia:

```
void elevarFraccionAlaN(int N, float & Potencia){
    float obtenerDivisionDecimal, i;

    i=1;
    Potencia=1;

    while(i<=N){
        Potencia=Potencia*obtenerDivisionDecimal;
        i++;
    }   
}
```

¿Por qué no me gusta esta solución? Porque las funciones deberían usar el `return` para devolver valores, que para eso está.

Ahora bien, presta atención al siguiente punto:

**Bonus**

- `i` **no debería** ser `float` sino `int`, ya que únicamente la usas para almacenar números enteros. Usar un `float` para gestionar enteros es una pésima idea.
- `obtenerDivisionDecimal` **no está inicializada**, luego no te extrañes si la función te devuelve resultados aleatorios o, cuanto menos, extraños.

Comment: Es un trabajo de la U e indica que debe usarse void, por eso no me explico cómo hacerlo de tal forma, como dices utilizar un float sería lo ideal. Creo que lo haré así, aunque falle el puntaje pero al menos compila xD